# "al darte cuenta de la de cosas": what is la referring to?

Tags: gramática, pronombres

I ran across the following sentence and am confused about what "la" is referring to:

```
Te quedarás perplejo y te entusiasmarás al darte cuenta de la de cosas interesantes que tenías al alcance de la mano...
```

I see from a google search that this pattern, "al darte cuenta de la de cosas", shows up in a few other places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"La de cosas" means "la cantidad de cosas".

In general, in a construction of the form

> definite article + noun + "de" + noun phrase

you can drop the noun if it can be inferred. E.g.:

> El juguete del niño es caro. **El de** la niña es barato.
>
> La ropa del niño es rosa. **La de** la niña es azul.

You can alternatively see it as treating "de" + noun phrase as an adjective. E.g.:

> **Lo del** otro día fue una vergüenza.

"La de" can also be used to denote a sizeable amount of something:

> Verás **la de** hostias que te voy a meter si no te callas.

which means

> Verás **la cantidad de** hostias que te voy a meter si no te callas.

or

> Es gracioso escuchar **la de** tonterías que suelta cuando se emborracha.

which means

> Es gracioso escuchar **la cantidad de** tonterías que suelta cuando se emborracha.

Note that, while article + "de" is not particularly informal in itself, using "la de" with this meaning is very informal.

You can also use definite article + "con"/"sin", to a certain extent. You could say:

> No me gusta el café solo. **El con** leche está más rico.

However, definite article + "con"/"sin" is informal to the point that it may be perceived as wrong, and it gets awkward when you try to use it in longer sentences.

There's also definite article + (relative pronoun) "que", which can work in a similar way:

> Me gustan los garbanzos, pero no **los que** tú haces.

Although not all instances of definite article + "que" work like that:

> Real Decreto 463/2020, de 14 de marzo, por **el que** se declara el estado de alarma para la gestión de la situación de crisis sanitaria ocasionada por el COVID-19.